# Integration $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I solve the following integral.
$\int\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)^3}$

$\int x^{-1}\ln(x)^{-3}$

I did $u=\ln(x)^{-3}$ $du=-3\ln(x)^{-4}(1/x)$ $dv=x^{-1}$ v=$ln(x)$

and I get

$\ln(x)^{-3}ln(x)-(-3)\int\ln(x)^{-4}\ln(x)\frac{1}{x}$

But I am stuck how would I proceed.

Comment: Substitute $u = \ln x$.

Comment: But then what would I do with negative expoent

Comment: You know how to integrate $u^{-3}$.

Comment: As other people have pointed out, it's easier to use substitution.  However, you could finish your solution by solving $\int \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^3} dx=(\ln x)^{-2}+3\int \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^3} dx$ by bringing the second term on the right to the lefthand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do **not** need integration by parts. Simple substitution works well:

Let $u = \ln x$. $\quad du = \dfrac 1x\,dx = x^{-1} \,dx$

$$\int \dfrac{\,dx}{x(\ln x)^3}=\int \dfrac{(\ln x)^{-3}}{x} \,dx = \int u^{-3} \,du$$

I trust you can take it from here :)

Comment: u should be to the -3rd power, not the 3rd power. It doesn't really affect the problem too much, though.

Comment: I am not sure if It matter but yeah the original problem was $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)^3}$

Comment: I think it is the same as what I wrote initially..

Comment: Yes I can take it from here thankss

Comment: You're welcome, @Fernando!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback! +1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$(\ln x)'=\frac1x.$$

> Then $\int \frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^3}=\int \frac{d(\ln x)}{(\ln x)^3}=-\frac{1}{2(\ln x)^2}+C.$

Comment: I hate to be nitpicky...don't forget the "+C" =)

Comment: OK. :-) ${}{}{}{}$